# Adding DIV Element Into IFRAME Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Summernote textarea change YouTube URL into `<iframe>` using this code :

```
    $video = $('<iframe>')
      .attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeId)
      .attr('width', '640').attr('height', '360');
```

and it turns the YouTube URL into this :

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_qxxxxxxc" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but I want to insert bootstrap responsive class, so it will end like this :

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_qxxxxxxc" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I tried to modify the javascript like this :

```
$video = 
    $('<div>').attr('class','embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9');
    $('<iframe>')
    .attr('class', 'embed-responsive-item')
    .attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeId)
    .attr('width', '640').attr('height', '360');
```

and it end up like this as result :

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" frameborder="0"></div>
```

how to keep the iframe and add div element? thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 $video =    
    $('<iframe>')
    .attr('class', 'embed-responsive-item')
    .attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeId)
    .attr('width', '640').attr('height', '360');

 $div = $('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"></div>').append($video);
```

---

**Your Problem Was**

```
$video = 
    $('<div>').attr('class','embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9'); //the semicolon indicates end of line. So your $video ends here

//below line of code does nothing. It just creates a iframe with all mentioned stuff and then???? its not put into any use.
    $('<iframe>')
    .attr('class', 'embed-responsive-item')
    .attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeId)
    .attr('width', '640').attr('height', '360');
```

Comment: your code works, bro! but it end like this : `<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" frameborder="0"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/_xxxxxx" width="640" height="360"></iframe></div>`, the `frameborder="0"` now stick to div element, not iframe.

Comment: I dont see any `frameborder="0"` in the syntax, I guess you have some other script appending it. Can you confirm?

Comment: hold on... let me check... but, I guess so... it added with other scripts.

Comment: there's code like this under your code : `if ($video) {
        $video.attr('frameborder', 0);
        range.create().insertNode($video[0]);
        afterCommand($editable);
      }`
that cause frameborder stick to div

Comment: problem solved bro... I know how to solved it. thanks for your enlightenment!

Comment: @RobertHanson :) glad to hear that, I was jut wondering even with that syntax its still pointing to iframe and it must work fine.

Comment: @RobertHanson If this solution resolved your issue Can you mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for today's date if you're using `summernote v0.8.16`

you may refer below code for youtube specific

```
$video = external_root_jQuery_commonjs2_jquery_commonjs_jquery_amd_jquery_default()('<iframe allowfulscreen allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture">').attr('frameborder', 0).attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeId + (start > 0 ? '?start=' + start : ''));

$video.addClass('note-video-clip embed-responsive-item');
$video = $('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"></div>').append($video);
return $video[0];
```

You'll find this code line somewhere around `9000` to `9100` or you may just search for `$video =` hope this helps